# How to properly specify a country code top-level domain in a mutt search

Tags: mutt

I use mutt as my email reader or mail user agent, MUA. I'm getting mail from countries that have no business addressing me. Examples: China `.cn`, Russia `.ru`, Argentina `.ar`. I want to mark all messages for deletion by searching the bodies of the messages for any reference to those country-code top-level domains, but I'm having problems crafting a regexp. I have tried `~B\.ar` and `~B'.ar'` (using Argentina as an example) but these seem to not be properly interpreting my attempt to specify a period.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *mutt Advanced Usage manual [Patterns](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2)*:

> ~B EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the whole message

There needs to be a space between the `~B` and the `EXPR`.

I would suggest trying:

`~B \.ar$`

Which will match any word that ends in `.ar` in the whole message.

Answer (score 0):

Search patterns use regex, so `.ar` would match `kar`, `xar`, etc. Use `\.ar` to specify (escape) the period.

I suggest searching using `~f \.ar`, which will match .ar addresses in the `From` field, which is more specific than using `~B`, which searches both the header and the entire message.

Other useful patterns:

- `~e`: Matches in the `Sender` field.
- `~L`: Matches "messages either originated or received by"
- `~s`: Matches the subject.